# Test with headless Chrome in Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, headless

I DO successfully run headless Chrome with Selenium standalone server with

```
chromeOptions: {
    args: ["--headless"]
}
```

But when I decide to push it to Selenium Grid, it didn't work for me.

How can I correctly configure headless mode for Selenium Node/Chrome

I'm also feeling confused on where should I configure the remote Chrome instance. I can see that there is a set of capabilities config in client side. I can also see a set of capabilities in Selenium Node config file.
I set headless flag in both side but both of them didn't work at all.

Thanks

Comment: Try adding "--disable-gpu"

Comment: Your binary versions please.

Comment: Sorry for so late, my selenium version is 3.6.1

Answer (score 1):

#### Python

When creating a `Remote()` webdriver object, as an argument you can add `desired_capabilities` which is a dictionary like this:

```
{'platform': 'ANY', 'browserName': 'chrome', 'javascriptEnabled': True, 'goog:chromeOptions': {'extensions': [], 'args': ['headless', 'window-size=1920x1080']}, 'version': ''}
```

There is also `to_capabilities()` method of `ChromeOptions()` object which returns configured Chrome options as dictionary.

This is the example of how to do it:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
capabilities = {'browserName': 'chrome', 'javascriptEnabled': True}
capabilities.update(chrome_options.to_capabilities())
drv_chrome = webdriver.Remote(command_executor = 'http://192.168.122.60:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities = capabilities)
```